# Hide custom admin section from user

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I have created my own custom controller and added the section on  admin (community version). Is there any way for only specific users to see the section and not all of them? (let's say we want only the administrator to be able to see this section).

I know that I have to set the permissions of the section in the DB but it is not clear to me how.

The `ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID` that I inserted when creating the section was "-1"

```sql
INSERT INTO blc_admin_sec_perm_xref (ADMIN_SECTION_ID, ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID) VALUES (1, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The next step here is adding an entry in `BLC_ADMIN_ROLE_PERMISSION_XREF` to give your role the new permission.

For example, if you want your "Admin Master Access" role with ID -1 to be able to view your section, you would perform:

```sql
INSERT INTO BLC_ADMIN_ROLE_PERMISSION_XREF (ADMIN_ROLE_ID, ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID) VALUES (-1, -1);
```

This should allow only your "Admin Master Access" role users to see the section.